# Count row with condition per group

Tags: r, dplyr

This code:

```
Group <- rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each = 3)
Days <- c(21,21,19,18,21,21,11,21,19)
State <- c("OK", "NOK", "OK", "OK", "NOK", "OK", "OK", "OK", "NOK")

data <- data.frame(Group = Group, Days = Days, State = State)
```

create this data frame:

```
> data
  Group Days State
1     A   21    OK
2     A   21   NOK
3     A   19    OK
4     B   18    OK
5     B   21    OK
6     B   21    OK
7     C   11   NOK
8     C   21    OK
9     C   19   NOK
```

I often use `group_by` and `summarizes` of `dplyr` do get parameters of groups (eg. A, B, C). But I couldn't figure ou a simple way to get the amnount of OKs and NOKs per Group (eg. percentage NOK). The result I expect would by:

```
  > result
      Group   %NOK
    1     A   33.3
    2     B      0
    3     C   66.6
```

In a further step I wish to count proportions with additional conitions. For example: Count the amount of NOKs, where days > 20 for every group. My really straightforward solution would be:

```
data %>% group_by(Group) %>% nrow(filter(Days < 20, State == "NOK")) / n() * 100
```

but it would be nice, if you could give my a solution, that is actually working ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can use `summarise`

```
data %>% 
   group_by(Group) %>% 
   summarise(NOKPer = round(100*sum(State=="NOK")/n(),2))
#     Group NOKPer
#    (chr)  (dbl)
# 1     A  33.33
# 2     B   0.00
# 3     C  66.67
```

For the second case

```
data %>%
    group_by(Group) %>% 
    summarise(NOKPer = round(100*sum(State=="NOK" & Days >20)/n(), 2))
```

---

This can be solved easily using `base R`

```
prop.table(table(data[-2]),1)
```

and with the second condition

```
prop.table(table(subset(data, Days>20, select=c("Group", "State"))),1)
```